# What is the number 0.05 in the calculation of contrast ratio between colors?

Tags: color, color-scheme, contrast, color-blindness

To calculate contrast ratio the following formula is used ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#contrast-ratiodef)):

```
(L1 + 0.05) / (L2 + 0.05)
```

where:

L1 is the relative luminance of the lighter of the colors, and

L2 is the relative luminance of the darker of the colors.

My question is, what is the number 0.05 in this formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Gamma correction and RGB constants are derived from the Standard Default Color Space for the Internet (sRGB), and the **0.05 offset is included to compensate for contrast ratios that occur when a value is at or near zero, and for ambient light effects**. - http://juicystudio.com/article/luminositycontrastratioalgorithm.php

Comment: Further discussion can be found in this Github issue, it gets quite technical: https://github.com/w3c/wcag/issues/695

Answer (score 2):

Well, without it, if L2 is darkest black, which has a [relative luminance](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#relativeluminancedef) of 0, the ratio would be undefined since you can't divide by zero.

So they decided to add a small factor to make sure the ratio is always defined. The consequence of using 0.05 is that the maximum ratio is 1.05 : 0.05 = 21 : 1.

> *Note 1:* Contrast ratios can range from 1 to 21 (commonly written 1:1 to 21:1).

Why they chose exactly this number, I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

The 0.05 addition was intended to represent the flare on the face of the monitor from ambient illumination that was typical of CRT type displays, this flare value is recited in Annex D of the sRGB standard for **Typical Viewing Conditions**

I discuss the history in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/w3c/wcag/issues/1705#issuecomment-1027058976)

Unfortunately, adding the flare value to both sides of the formula doesn't actually correct the problem with using a simple contrast ratio in terms of its lack of perceptual uniformity, so that algorithm really only works when the background is very light or white.

Ratios are not the best way to model human perception of text contrast at suprathreshold levels on a self illuminated display. For an example of a contrast method that uses a more comprehensive model of contrast perception, see [**apcacontrast.com**](https://apcacontrast.com) *(disclosure, I am the creator of the APCA algorithm).*

Comment: [Some room for improvement in contrast](https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/7vadpzM43lae.jpg?o=1) (Firefox, Android 12 in dark mode)

Comment: Hi @LukeSawczak  **YIKES** that purple link text is an ***APCA fail*** regardless of text size. At Lc -24 it's below the minimum for text cut off.  Where did you see that and how is that related to Firefox?

Comment: It's a screenshot from your site, and I quote Firefox only to help you track down the platform on which it displays like that. I can give more detail if it's helpful.

Comment: HI @LukeSawczak thanks for the clarification, but my site in question **does not have a dark mode** at all, meaning this is a *forced dark mode* that Firefox created. Are you using an extension, or the built-in forced dark mode of Firefox? What version of Firefox? I tried using the forced dark mode for Firefox on iOS and it doesn't have this problem. I'll take a look at this on android devices when I get back to the lab. Sounds like some bug reports need to be filed at Mozilla. Per your example, Firefox Night on Android is inverting the background, but not inverting some text colors properly.

Comment: Indeed, it's Firefox's built-in dark mode. No extension. Note that it's not even something I had to choose; the browser setting is on "Use device setting" and my Android is what I set to use dark mode. I agree that it's probably ultimately a Firefox deficiency, and it's sad that so many sites fail to work quite as intended in Firefox, but even so, when 90% of the sites I visit get it right, I figure it's doable even if one has to fiddle with what "ought to" work universally.

Comment: Hi @LukeSawczak Thank you for bringing it to my attention. I was not able to replicate the problem with Firefox on the Fire flavor of android, and also not able to replicate with Firefox on iOS, nor Firefox on OSX. You mentioned Android 12? What device please? And no extensions? The page in question should always be in light mode, and it is incorrect for any faux dark mode to invert the background without inverting the other colors as well. Something is wrong somewhere, and I'd like to get to the bottom of it... Thank you...

Comment: Ahh, guess what. I didn't look carefully enough. It is an extension. [Dark Reader](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader). I assumed that none of my extensions from desktop were here on mobile, but it turns out that one alone bridges the gap. Sorry!

Comment: Hi @LukeSawczak whew! thank you for getting back to me, I suspected it might've been an extension... I like dark reader actually, it's pretty cool, but if it's not set up for a particular site sometimes it doesn't get it right.... Thanks for clarifying!